# git pull one version but push another

Tags: git

In git bash on my local branch I wrote:

```
git pull production master
```

I checked the files and they seem to be the same as the ones in the remote server.. everything's OK.

Afterwards I wrote:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'ggggg'
```

And here is the weird part: the response was: "nothing to commit working directory clean".

This is strange because before I pulled from the remote branch many files were different

You can guess what comes next- To check if indeed my local branch is in sync with the remote one (And it does seem so by looking at the files) I wrote:

```
git push production master
```

And completely ruined the remote branch by pushing an old version (:

so.. what am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure the files were saved at the time you did the git add .? Or were they edited but not saved? Cause your sequence of commands seems correct to me. The only thing I would advise you to do is to use git add -A instead of git add . to account for the deleted files cause git add . doesn't care about deleted files, but your problem didn't occur with deleted files, did it?

Comment: I assume there were some deleted files as well.. but a lot of other changes were made too... including new folders etc... but thanks for the tip- I was wondering why I had to do "git rm" all the time (:

Answer (score 0):

The command `git pull` changes your working directory with the contents of the remote.  When it completes the working directory is consistent with the `git` index/repository.  Thus, there is nothing to `add` nor `commit`.  Essentially, the `git pull` does the `add` and `commit` automatically for you.

The problem you may be seeing is a result of being on a branch other than 'master'.  You pulled from 'master' into branch 'foo'; everything merged smoothly; then you pushed 'foo' back to 'master' and changed the remote.  Perhaps.